# how to detect previous url path react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using React, and I am trying to detect the previous path / url that the user is coming from within my app. so if they are coming from `/register` and land on `/index`, then how do I log, on `/index`, that the user came from `/register`. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried to look at library `react-router`?

Comment: @webduvet I have, but I couldn't find anything that worked in my code. I tried `props.history.location.pathname` as well, and that didn't work, not sure what else to try.

Comment: Are both paths inside the same react app?

Comment: @lifeisfoo yes they are

Comment: what didn't work? you perhaps should put some effort either in trying or posting a proper question with details of what have you tried and what does not work.

Comment: @webduvet I tried `props.history.location.state`, and that didn't work, it retuned `undefined`. I also tried `props.history.location.pathname`, and that gives the current page, not the one it is coming from

Comment: because that is history object. the very same one as in `window.history`.

Comment: You could create a history array of your own. After every navigation, push the current path to the array. The previous path would then be the last index minus one.

Comment: since you use react-router you can store the visited routes in some object.

Comment: thanks for the replies everyone. I ended up storing the variables in some object

Answer (score 0):

you can save previous path in a **componentWillReceiveProps** lifecycle method.

```
<Route component={App}>
  {/* ... other routes */}
</Route>

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { prevPath: '' }
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
      this.setState({ prevPath: this.props.location })
    }
  }
})
```